# How do I update a JSON field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with a column called `data` that contains some JSON. If the `data` column for any given row in the table is not null, it will contain a JSON-encoded object with a key called `companyDescription`. The value associated with `companyDescription` is an arbitrary JavaScript object.

If I query my table like this

```
select data->>'companyDescription' from companies where data is not null;
```

I get rows like this

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"\n"}]}
```

I am trying to update all rows in the table so that the `companyDescription` values will be wrapped in another JSON-encoded JavaScript object in the following manner:

```
{"type":"quill","content":{"ops":[{"insert":"\n"}]}}
```

Here's what I have tried, but I think it won't work because the `->>` operator is for selecting some JSON field as *text*, and indeed it fails with a syntax error.

```
update companies
set data->>'companyDescription' = CONCAT(
  '{"type":"quill","content":',
  (select data->>'companyDescription' from companies),
  '}'
);
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function [`jsonb_set`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). Currently `XML` or `JSON` values are immutable. You cannot to update some parts of these values. You can replace these values by some new modified value.

```
postgres=# select * from test;
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                  v                                   │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"companyId": 10, "companyDescription": {"ops": [{"insert": "\n"}]}} │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select jsonb_build_object('type', 'quill', 'content', v->'companyDescription') from test;
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                    jsonb_build_object                     │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"type": "quill", "content": {"ops": [{"insert": "\n"}]}} │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)

postgres=# select jsonb_set(v, ARRAY['companyDescription'], jsonb_build_object('type', 'quill', 'content', v->'companyDescription')) from test;
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                             jsonb_set                                              │
╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ {"companyId": 10, "companyDescription": {"type": "quill", "content": {"ops": [{"insert": "\n"}]}}} │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

So you final statement can looks like:

```
update companies
  set data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, 
                       ARRAY['companyDescription'], 
                       jsonb_build_object('type', 'quill', 
                                          'content', data->'companyDescription'))
  where data is not null;
```

Comment: Thank you; that explains why all my previous search results showed examples in `jsonb` instead of `json`. How do I get the `v` in your example? I'm trying to use my original select, but I am not sure how map each row to itself. Do I need to use some kind of loop? Here's what I am trying: http://ix.io/2m5u

Comment: @JezenThomas - `v` is column name, it is `data`. I'll fix this query

Comment: Excellent, thanks. This does indeed work; just needs the explicit `data::JSONB` typecast.